# Angular 1.5 correct way to synchronize changes in a component

Tags: angularjs

I'm wondering what would be the best way to treat the following scenario:

I have a component (PeopleSelector) that loads objects of type Person and allows the user to select some of them. The data load logic (using a REST service) is proprietary of the component, so it should be private to it. The selected persons are included in an array of Person objects, included in a double bind.

In a container page, this component will be used, and the selected persons must be set (using an array of ids received from other service).

Problem is, the parent controller may receive the list of ids before the available persons are loaded in the child component (as services are asynchronous), so it cannot obtain the list of persons filtering the available objects in the child component.

So, how should I implement this use case?

Thanks

Comment: Hey I'm trying to wrap my head around what exactly it is you are trying to accomplish, if you have already written some code posting it would be a great help. But from the sound of it I think if you store all logic and data in your parent controller, I think it might alleviate the issue. The peopleselector component should be a 'dumb' component, and should not update any internal properties but rather update properties on the parent.

Comment: If I understand well, this is very easy. Just combine the promises from the 2 services (options and values) with `$q.all()` and pass the resolved values to the control. [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mL7dnz5b/) gives an example using `$timeout` instead of real HTTP calls.

Comment: I'm sorry if my explanation is not good, but english is not my mother language. What I'm trying to accomplish is to decouple children components from parent components (view and logic). Child component will have objects loaded from a REST service and the parent will only know arrays of ids. Problem is, the parent has to notify the child to select the objects with the required ids, and only with all the items are loaded from the REST